# How to force Sublime to use different `flake8` per project?

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, flake8

I've project which uses Python 3.6, in which I use [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) unpacking syntax.

Flake8Lint in Sublime uses my default install of `flake8`, which happens to be Python 2.7 and marks these as a syntax error. 
[image: E901 on dictionary unpacking]

I've been looking for an option to select different `flake8` binary on per project basis, but I don't see a way to configure that in `.flake8`, `setup.cfg` or even `.sublimelinterrc`?

Am I missing something, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem today with python3 and fixed it via Sublime Project Settings (Project > Edit Project):

```
{
    "settings":
    {
        "flake8lint": {
            // "python_interpreter": "auto",
            "python_interpreter": ".../dev/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/python",
        }
    },
}
```

Hope that helps.